# Lubuntu vs Ubuntu for development

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

I am using Ubuntu on my 1.6 Ghz processor (**using virtualization, my primary OS is Windows 10**) and it is being too laggy, I am a **computer science student**, and thus is it a nice decision to switch to **Lubuntu from Ubuntu** for **development purposes**? Or tell me **any other flavour** suitable for me.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 how can i do that?

Comment: If you go with Ubuntu there is a new minimal installation option in Ubuntu 18.04 that saves hard drive space by not installing unnecessary applications. Ubuntu minimal installation option [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMgbB.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your development computer is very low on hardware resources. Lubuntu 32-bit is a wise choice because of the extreme load that virtualization in Windows 10 will put on your computer's 1.6GHz processor. Lubuntu is the most lightweight and minimal Ubuntu edition.

[image]
<sup>**Lubuntu 17.10**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: can i do all the coding stuff same like in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you can do all coding the same as in Ubuntu, but clearly you are not going to be able to run a resource hog like Android Studio on this computer on either operating system.

Comment: can i build packages and participate in most open source communities?

Comment: Your capabilities will be limited if you are running any machine, physical or virtual, that has less than 4GB RAM.

Comment: i have 4 GB ram, should i dual boot, will i be able to use my whole ram with dual boot?

Comment: The maximum amount of RAM that you can safely allocate to the guest OS in a virtual machine cannot exceed half of the total amount of the physical RAM. The rest has to be allocated to the host OS to prevent crashing and instability.

Comment: how about dual boot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77121/discussion-between-karel-and-rahul-gurung).

Comment: Windows 10 is the host OS. Windows 10 will be sick if there is less than 2GB RAM available for running the host OS. Also the OS that needs the most RAM should ideally be installed as the host OS. The smartest way to install Linux on this machine is by dual booting Linux and Windows 10, that way both OSs get to use all 4GB of the available physical RAM in this machine.